# Android, NDK, JNI, "cannot initialize a variable of type 'long *' with an rvalue of type 'jlong *' "

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I want to get a Java `long[]` array and ultimately pass it to the function `powerEstimate` that need a `const long` type in input.
This is the function definition in c++:

```
void powerEstimate(const double rr_data[], const long timeRR_data[])
```

This is the code I use to get the Java `long[]` array:

```
Java_com_example_matteofabris_stressmanagement_acquisition_SewAcquisition_powerEstimateNative(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject, jdoubleArray rr_j_, jlongArray timeRR_j_) {         
    // GET
    double* rr_j = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(rr_j_, NULL);
    long* timeRR_j = env->GetLongArrayElements(timeRR_j_, NULL);

    // TODO
    powerEstimate(rr_j, timeRR_j)
```

When I build it, I get this error:

```
/Users/matteofabris/AndroidStudioProjects/StressManagement/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:35:11: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'long *' with an rvalue of type 'jlong *' (aka 'long long *')
long* timeRR_j = env->GetLongArrayElements(timeRR_j_, NULL);
```

Can someone explain why I get this error and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance for the patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` is only 32 bits on Windows (which looks to be your platform). However, a Java `jlong` is 64 bits.

You could use `__int64*` in your native code in place of `long`, as that's also how `jlong` is defined in `jni_md`:

```
__int64* timeRR_j = env->GetLongArrayElements(timeRR_j_, NULL);
```

and

```
void powerEstimate(const double rr_data[], const __int64
               timeRR_data[])
```

If you can't change the `powerEstimate` function, then you could switch to an `int[]` on the Java side, as `int`s are 32 bits, just like the native `long`.

Comment: `jlong * timeRR_j = env->GetLongArrayElements(timeRR_j_, NULL);` and `void powerEstimate(const double rr_data[], const jlong timeRR_data[])` would be better as it's portable.